# Instantiating a class inside a method

Tags: c#, oop, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

Is it possible to do this

```
void Instantiate(Class c) {
   c = new Class();
}

Class c1 = null;
Instantiate(c1);
c1.property .....gives me null reference exception
```

Can a class be instantiated inside a method and be used outside it?

Comment: You have to pass `c1` by reference.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, thanks for the reply mate, but dont the reference types get their reference passed in when you pass them to a method? oh does it happen only if its instantiated before its passed to the method?

Comment: I updated my answer with an explanation. Long story short - in C# all parameters are passed by value by default. For reference type the value is the reference (address) of the object. But that reference is copied, so if you modify it inside the method it doesn't reflect outside of the method. You need to pass it by `ref` to make that happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you have to pass the argument by reference:

```
void Instantiate(ref Class c) {
   c = new Class();
}

Class c1 = null;
Instantiate(ref c1);
```

All parameters are passed by value by default. In case of reference types the reference is the value being passed. Because of that if you change internal state of the object it will be visible outside of the method (e.g. adding an element to a list). But, but you can't replace the entire instance - that change won't be visible to the caller.

Let's say you have a `List<T>`:

```
var myList = new List<T>();
```

let's assume it's initialized in some memory location `0x1234`. Now you pass it to a method which takes `List<T>`:

```
void doSomethingWithAList(List<T> list)
{
}
```

And later

```
doSomethingWithAList(myList);
```

At this point both `myList` outside of the method and `list` inside `doSomethingWithAList` point at the same addres `(0x1234)`. If you do `list.Add(default(T))` and later call`myList.Lenghth` you'll get back 1, because they are both pointing at the same object at `0x1234`.

However, if inside `doSomethingWithAList` you assign a new list to `list`:

```
void doSomethingWithAList(List<T> list)
{
    list = new List<T>();
}
```

only `list` points at that new object. `myList` still points at `0x1234`.

Once you make the method take `List<T>` by reference updating what `list` points too will also update what `myList` points to outside of the method.

Comment: Understand, Thanks once again mate!

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion is that all parameters are passed by value to another method. So when you pass in a reference type into a method, a copy of the reference gets passed into the method.

In your example, c1 points to null initially. When you call instantiate, a copy of c1, I'll name it c1_ is created (which points to null) and c1_ gets passed into the method Instantiate, not c1.

There are two ways to get your code to work. The first way is the use of the ref keyword. The ref keyword will allow c1 to be passed into the method.

```
void Instantiate(ref Class c) {
   c = new Class();
}
```

And call it as such

```
Instantiate(ref c1);
```

I would recommend that you use a return type in this specific example.

```
Class Instantiate() {
   return new Class();
}
```

You can use the method the following way.

```
Class c1 = Instantiate();
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Paul , make more sense!